# Including markdown files before document body (pandoc)

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I'm struggling with inserting markdown files using -B option. It's inserted but for some reason markdown syntax if not recognized when compiling a final PDF document. What can be a reason for that?

I was trying to search for some imfo related to my problem but it seems like it happens only for me.